# Javafx, Itext7, maven dependencies and setting up the proper module-info.java file

Tags: maven, javafx, dependencies, pom.xml, module-info

Beginner here; I am creating a project with JavaFX and Itext7 and I don't understand how maven dependencies work. I am constructing this project on vsCode and this is how I have my dependencies set up in my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- always needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- always needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- only needed for forms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- only needed for PDF/A -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- only needed for digital signatures -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- only needed for barcodes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then in my module-info.java file, I was able to get the desired imports by using the following code,

```
requires transitive kernel;
requires transitive io;
requires transitive forms;
requires transitive layout;
requires transitive barcodes;
requires transitive pdfa;
requires transitive sign;
```

For each one of these I am getting the same error -> Name of automatic module 'kernel' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.

This is happening for each of these lines - ie: Name of automatic module 'io'... etc.

Now I created a jar file of the project and it runs when I run it from terminal but it doesn't work when I click the jar icon from my desktop. After running from terminal I get the following message, WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @5a65309b'.

How can I resolve these issues and get the project to work when the jar file is clicked from desktop?

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Itext7 Jars not loading in properly to javafx project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75052446/itext7-jars-not-loading-in-properly-to-javafx-project/75053196#75053196)

Comment: Creating a packaged app is a different question than your questions about the module system.  As noted in the answer to the duplicate, in this case, it is best for you to create a non-modular app.  That means you can’t use jlink for distribution.  Because you use JavaFX, a single executable app jar is also not recommended.  Your best option is likely jpackage, perhaps using [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX). More [info on packaging in the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Itext7 Jars not loading in properly to javafx project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75052446/itext7-jars-not-loading-in-properly-to-javafx-project)