# Itext7 Jars not loading in properly to javafx project

Tags: maven, javafx, dependencies, itext, itext7

I've got this dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.18</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

And in my module-info.java file I have the following

```
requires transitive kernel;
```

which produces the following warning, "Name of automatic module 'kernel' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name."

What can I do to get rid of this warning?

I tried changing it to

```
requires transitive com.itextpdf.kernel;
```

but then I get the following error, "com.itextpdf.kernel cannot be resolved to a module"

I tried a bunch of other similar lines of code but nothing worked. What can I change the code to in order to remove the error/warning?

Answer (score 1):

itext7 currently isn't modular.

You can contact the developers and ask them to make it modular.

In the meantime, complex, non-modular systems like this are difficult to use from a modular project.  Even if you get that to work via the automatic module system or hacking in module info via something like moditect, it pretty much destroys any potential benefit of the project being modular, and it runs the software in a way it was never designed to work.

So, make your project non-modular:

- remove the `module-info.java` from your project.
- source the javafx modules using either:

  - VM arguments pointing adding them to the module path OR
  - from a JRE/JDK distribution that includes them, e.g. BellSoft Liberica "Full JDK" or Azul Zulu "JDK FX".

For further instructions on working with non-modular JavaFX projects, see the getting started documentation at: [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

> I am not sure what "not modular" means but how can that be true if the itext7 website gives maven dependencies to incorporate into your pom.xml?

Non-modular means that you don't define a module-info.java in your project.

Read [understanding modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) and the documentation I linked at openjfx.io to understand the basics of the JavaFX module system and how it can be used in a JavaFX application.

[Maven modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and [Java Platform modules](https://openjdk.org/jeps/261) are different things, they have the same name "module" but one is a build-time definition and the other is a runtime definition.  Also, a [maven dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) is just a dependency, it is not a Maven module or a Java Platform module.  Though you can depend on artifacts built by a maven module and you can execute those artifacts through the Java Platform module system (if they are compatible with it).

itext7 is not built as a Java Platform module.  The software has no `module-info.java` and it does not define an automatic module name for itself either. Given that your software is depending on non-modular software, your software should not be modular either (in my opinion).

Comment: I am not sure what "not modular" means but how can that be true if the itext7 website gives maven dependencies to incorporate into your pom.xml?

Comment: I edited the question to reply to your comment.